# C++ Converting Fahrenheit to Celsius

Tags: c++

Here is a screenshot to help illustrate my problem:

[image: screenshot]

I'm running an Apache server. Now the user will enter a fahrenheit number into an html page and that will take them to this program to do the conversion. As you can see it is not calculating right. It is taking the Fahrenheit number and for some reason adding extra numbers to it and even letters?? Anyway, can anyone PLEASE help me edit my code to get this working? Thanks so much!!

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <windows.h>

    using namespace std;





    //(Include the c++ getvar comment block and code here)

    int getvar(char *var, char *dest, char *stream)
    {  
        char *vptr;
        int size, i=0, j=0, hex; /* ptr+i to src, ptr+j to dest */ 

        vptr=strstr(stream, var);  

        if(vptr) ; 
        else return(1); /* 1 for a checkbox thats off */

        if((vptr==stream)||(*(vptr-1)=='&')) ; 
        else return(-1); /* -1 for a var that appears in error */

        size=(int) strlen(var)+1; /* +1 accounts for the = */

        while(*(vptr+size+i)!='&') 
        {      
                if(*(vptr+size+i)=='+') /* output a space */           
                    *(dest+j)=' ';     
                else if(*(vptr+size+i)=='%') /* hex character */           
                        {              
                            sscanf(vptr+size+i+1,"%2x",&hex);              
                            *(dest+j)=(char)hex;               
                            i+=2;          
                        }      
            else *(dest+j)=*(vptr+size+i);     
                i++; j++;  
            }  
        *(dest+j)='\0';
            return(0);
}
```

Comment: Look carefully and note that it's outputting: "Fahrenheit temperature = 100<junk> Celsius temperature = 212<junk>"

Comment: One wonders why you're bothering, given that there are easily a dozen other sites on the web that do this.

Comment: Don't maliciously edit your question OP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
cout << "Fahrenheit Temperature = " <<(fahrenheitTemp)<<
cout << "Celsius Temperature = " <<(celsiustemp)<<
cout << "</body></html>\n";
```

The weird characters are because this is all one long statement, not three separate statements. It's printing `cout`'s address twice!

```
cout << "Fahrenheit Temperature = " <<(fahrenheitTemp)<< "<br/>\n"
     << "Celsius Temperature = " <<(celsiustemp)
     << "</body></html>\n";
```

Comment: @0x499602D2: It's an HTML line break.

Comment: @0x499602D2: it helps separate the items

Comment: @John Kugelman Thanks!! Now the only problem I have left.. is to get rid of the pesky line 'Content-type: text/html' that is displayed .... https://imageshack.us/scaled/large/22/help2o.jpg  ... when I delete that line the program doesn't run for some reason? How can I get rid of that, I'm looking to display just the time and conversion.

Comment: @MarianoJeter: you are outputting it twice..that's why you see it. As to why your program stops working. Who knows

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your problem with extra characters, but your formula is wrong due to order of operations.

You have:

```
celsiustemp = fahrenheitTemp - 32.0 * (5.0/9.0);
```

This is equivalent to:

```
 celsiustemp = fahrenheitTemp - (32.0 * (5.0/9.0));
```

Which is not the correct conversion formula.

You should use:

```
 celsiustemp = (fahrenheitTemp - 32.0) * (5.0/9.0);
```

Multiplication and division operators have higher precedence than addition and subtraction in C++, same as in scientific notation.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<math.h>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

double ferentocelsious(double feren)
{
    return 5 * (feren - 32) / 9;
}
int main(void)
{
    double ferenhit;
    cout << "Enter the temprature in ferenhit:\t";
    cin >> ferenhit;
    cout << ferenhit << " ferenhit temprature to celcious is:  " << ferentocelsious(ferenhit) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The OP is looking for a solution, not a rewrite. Could you explain what is wrong with his code.